# What is the best Python IDE for Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s a good IDE for Python on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893162/whats-a-good-ide-for-python-on-the-mac)

Hi,

I'm going to start a quite big python project development under Mac OS X. What is the best python IDE for Mac OS X -recommended freeware-.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893162/whats-a-good-ide-for-python-on-the-mac

Comment: @BoltClock: Not sure this is an exact duplicate of 893162, as that question seemed to be asking for the Python IDE that was similar to Eclipse, as opposed to the best one.

Comment: @BoltClock: having actually read a few answers on 893162 though, they do seem to cover a lot of the same territory that answers to this question would.

Comment: There is a list of IDEs in the other question. Btw, using "the best" in a question makes it subjective and argumentative is most cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pydev](http://pydev.org) with Eclipse.