# How do I get a Javascript runtime interpreter installed on OS X?

Tags: javascript, macos, terminal

With OS X Xcode installed one can run ruby code in terminal with ">ruby somefile.rb" command  (or from inside TextWrangler with the run command). You can also run a ruby interpreter from in terminal and type code in single lines while the interpreter retains variable objects.

Want same possibilities for Javascript. What must I install (if anything) on OS X to have that functionality? Not looking for an IDE as such just an interpreter that will run in Terminal.app?

I assume this is an allowed question for Stackoverflow based on other allowed questions about IDEs for various languages like:
[What's a good IDE for Python on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893162/whats-a-good-ide-for-python-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/). It's the V8 engine + libraries + REPL.

Although Node is usually used for web/network-related applications, at its core it's just a plain JS engine and can even be used for shell scripting.

You can install it [from the installer](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), `brew` or just `./configure && make` from a Node.js' tarball.

There's also [Rhino](https://www.mozilla.org/rhino/).

Comment: Thanks porneL. With node.js installed, if I use Run command in TextWrangler will I get error line numbers returned on runtime fatal errors?

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil I'm don't know how TextWrangler runs programs, but node will output error + line number + stack trace to `stderr`

Comment: Thanks. Which install method would you recommend for a UNIX/bash newb like me?

Comment: node.js is one click download & install on OS X now nodejs.org

Comment: Hi, I think it is not fair to say about Rhino as a "dead project" - it works fine on OpenJDK and Android and is updated regularly - https://github.com/mozilla/rhino

Answer (score 39):

There is a Javascript interpreter in the JavaScriptCore framework that comes with OS X.  The interpreter is called jsc and can be found at the following path:

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Helpers/jsc
```

There is a built-in function, `quit()`, which will exit interactive mode.

If you want to make it easier to use I suggest creating a symlink to a location in your path, e.g.:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Helpers/jsc /usr/local/bin
```

This will put a symbolic link in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Thanks mttrb, any links to tutorials/docs for working with the JavaScriptCore framework outside Xcode (which I'm not overly familiar with)?

Comment: There isn't really much more to it than running jsc in Terminal.app and then typing JavaScript to run.  Alternatively you can provide JavaScript in a file on the command line.  jsc -h will give you the options.  jsc has no relation to Xcode, the JavaScriptCore framework is the framework Safari uses for JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, to explain I'm used to seeing frameworks talked about in a Cocoa/Xcode contexts.

Comment: In El Capitan you'll get "Operation not permitted" when linking to /usr/bin because of rootless mode. I linked to /user/local/bin instead.

Comment: On 10.13 High Sierra (and perhaps above) the `jsc`binary is moved to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc`.

Comment: @andiOak That is the old location for `jsc`, this answer actually used to have that path but was updated when macOS moved it into `Helpers`. I just checked and it is still in `Helpers` on macOS Monterey (12.6).

Answer (score 2):

v8. Its the javascript engine used in google chrome. You have to compile it for mac OS X, though. Theres a good tutorial [here](http://kourge.net/node/123).

Comment: A simple way to install v8 on a Mac is with homebrew: brew install v8

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. Use console in your Browser: Browsers such as chrome,safari, firefox come buildtin with console which are cappable of running javascript. to open open console on chrome. Press **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **J**
2. Install Nodejs: As others have pointed out, try http://nodejs.org/ using which you can run javascript in terminal app similar to irb

Comment: Thanks looking for alternative to using Safari (currently using) and other environments (Apple's Quartz Composer) that happen to support JS.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Big Sur you can easily access you OS JavaScript interpreter by adding your local user binary folder.
You can create a new symlink in `/usr/local/bin` with

```
% ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/A/Helpers/jsc /usr/local/bin/
```

Then you can access the OS's JavaScript interpreter by just typing

```
% jsc
```

*Hint: Do not forget, that there is no `console` object, you can use `debug(...)` instead*

Answer (score 0):

**On macOS 10.13 High Sierra** the location for the `jsc` binary is:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc
```

Using @mttrb's answer simply replace the path if you're on High Sierra. Seems like this binary has moved around a lot during macOS versions, so you would have to look around under the `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/...` path to find the location of `jsc`.

### About documentation of `jsc`

The [JavaScriptCore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore) `Swift/Objective-C` framework of is a part of the Apple JavaScript additions for mac apps but the Apple Docs do very little to support the `jsc` binary. However, the original **webkit** *docs* do more:

https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JSC

Here you will find the functions mentioned in other answers here, like the `debug()` (replaces `console.log()`), the `quit()` (that exits terminal interactive shell mode) and so on.

### Other JavaScript shells

[Here is a list of a couple of JS shells](https://reference.codeproject.com/javascript/shells), many of which are cross-platform and can be installed using a single pre-compiled binary (such as JSDB):

https://reference.codeproject.com/javascript/shells